# When touch the region of GUI only gui-event respond?

Tags: user-interface, event-handling, unity-game-engine

I make a Scrollview.When i scroll the view, the scene below also respond.

How to make it only respond GUI event when touch the region of GUI component

Comment: [preventing mouse clicks from passing through gui](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16774/preventing-mouse-clicks-from-passing-through-gui-c.html) && [howto use GUI Utility hotControl](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/320344/how-to-use-guiutilityhotcontrol.html) maybe useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private float scroll_value;
private Rect vscroll_rect = new Rect(0,0,100,100);
void OnGUI () {
    scroll_value = GUI.VerticalScrollbar (vscroll_rect , scroll_value, 1.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
}
void Update() {
    // Cursor is inside verticalscroll rect, ignore it
    if (vscroll_rect.Contains(Input.mousePosition))return;
}
```

The only problem is that if you have several GUI elements in many different scripts they each need to test if Input.mouseCursor is inside a GUI element.  One easy way around that is to create a single script that manages GUI rects which you can call from any other script to check.